# Should I stay schtum?

Tags: united-kingdom

Without going into too much detail, my partner has made accusations against me to the police for which I am currently on bail while they investigate. I feel frustrated that his accusations are bogus but I do not have a voice. I've sought advice from a solicitor and been advised to stay schtum. But I feel that the whole thing could be nipped in the bud sooner if only my side of events were heard. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Talk to an attorney.

Comment: If you don't trust your lawyer's advice, then the best thing is to seek a second opinion from another lawyer.  It is not a good idea to seek advice from random people on the Internet who are not lawyers (or, at least, are not *your* lawyers).  For one thing, a consultation for a second opinion would be privileged, which your post here is not - what you write here could be used against you in court.

Comment: You can also have a more detailed conversation with your current lawyer - ask them to explain why they think it is best for you to remain silent.  Tell them what you would like to do instead, and ask them what they see as the risks and benefits of that.

Comment: One possible outcome is that the police conclude through their investigation that the allegations are without merit.  Perhaps this is why your lawyer advised you to keep quiet.  Be patient.  If a time arises when you *should* tell your side of the story, your lawyer will tell you to do so.  Also, from a different but related legal system, here's a fairly entertaining video explaining why lawyers should always advise their clients not to talk to the police: https://youtu.be/d-7o9xYp7eE

Comment: @RobertColumbia From the united-kingdom tag, and the use of the word "solictor" in the  question, looking for an "attorney" might be unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks, Robert, but I managed to work that one out 

Comment: @phoog police in the UK have different duties towards a suspect than US police. For example, cooperation or not with the police is a factor in sentencing if eventually convicted.

Comment: @DaleM I'm aware of that.  The advice in the video does not apply entirely to UK police interviews, but it could be modified to fit this situation by saying "don't speak unless spoken to, and don't talk to the police without your lawyer present."

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice, I have spoken with my solicitor and, for the time being, will try to be patient and remain schtum while the police do their investigation - I just hope they get their finger out. In the meantime, she’s advised me to collate all communications with him, which disprove his claims, until such time we might need them.

Answer (score 4):

> I've sought advice from a solicitor and been advised to stay schtum.

Enough said.